# DynamoDBMapper for conditional saves

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDBMapper and would like to conditionally save if and only if the hashkey and range key combination does not exist. I know there are ways to use UUIDs to reduce the possibility of a collision but I would like to protect myself by using conditional saves.

I came across [this article](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1JADUVTWF7SP2/Specifying-Conditional-Constraints-with-Amazon-DynamoDB-Mapper) that uses [DynamoDBSaveExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBSaveExpression.html) however I'm not able to specify that the condition is "hashkey AND rangekey" cannot exist. The [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBSaveExpression.html) specifies a `withConditionalOperator` method but I'm not able to see this in my class. I am using the latest aws java sdk also from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.9.15).

Any suggestions on how to conditionally save? Or what I may be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expectedAttributes = 
    ImmutableMap.<String, ExpectedAttributeValue>builder()
        .put("hashKey", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false))
        .put("rangeKey", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false))
        .build();
saveExpression.setExpected(expectedAttributes);
saveExpression.setConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.AND);
try {
    dynamoDBMapper.save(objectToSave, saveExpression);
} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
    //Handle conditional check
}
```

This uses the `public ExpectedAttributeValue(Boolean exists)` constructor, which just internally calls `setExists`.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I realised that I didn't sync my IDE with the gradle build and so the latest AWS SDK wasn't available in the IDE. Once I synced it the setConditionalOperator method became available. Thanks for your answer. It's correct so I have marked it as such.

Comment: Is that setConditionalOperator required? Is it not default to validate all the condition?

Comment: Found it! "If you omit ConditionalOperator, then AND is the default." from here under the conditional operator section: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html

Comment: I tries the exact same thing and it does not work for me. In my case they are not hashKey and rangeKey but on different attributes. Could you please help me.

Comment: I have a doubt - why use AND, rather than OR? Shouldn't it be: (hashKey does not exist) OR (rangeKey does not exist)? [Ref - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/ExpectedAttributeValue.html#withExists-java.lang.Boolean- ]

Comment: @aalosious For the combination of `hashKey` and `rangeKey`, it will not really matter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833351/dynamodb-put-item-if-hash-or-hash-and-range-combination-doesnt-exist/32833726#32833726) for an explanation of that.

Comment: @RaviKrishnaP conditional check does not work on attributes other than hash or range key in dynamoDB