# DynamoDBMapper save only if object doesn't exist

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Using the Java DynamoDBMapper, how can I save an object only if it doesn't already exist (based on primary key).  If it does exist, I want an exception or failure to be thrown, rather than having the existing entry updated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081401/dynamodbmapper-for-conditional-saves

Answer (score 15):

I believe you should be able to do this with a [DynamoDbSaveExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBSaveExpression.html) object that can apply to the mapper.

There's a tutorial on the AWS site [here](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1JADUVTWF7SP2/Specifying-Conditional-Constraints-with-Amazon-DynamoDB-Mapper), code shown below:

```
try {
    DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new       DynamoDBSaveExpression();
    Map expected = new HashMap();
    expected.put("status", new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(false));

    saveExpression.setExpected(expected);

    mapper.save(obj, saveExpression);
} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
    // This means our save wasn't recorded, since our constraint wasn't met
    // If this happens, the worker can simply look for a new task to work on
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be withExists(false)?

Comment: A parenthesis is missing after ("READY")
Here is the correct line: expected.put("status", new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue("READY")).withExists(true));

Comment: -1 as this answer only saves when the item already exists in the table.  This is the opposite of the result desired by the question.

Comment: changed to fix the boolean state (oops)

Comment: Edited the answer since when using `.withExists(false)` there must not be a value provided.

Comment: Does this make an additional read on the table? I believe it does!

Comment: No - it's all handled during the write

Answer (score 4):

Here's the correct way to implement this with the DynamoDBMapper:

```
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setUsername(username);
newUser.setPassword(password);

DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpr = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
saveExpr.setExpected(new ImmutableMap.Builder()
.put("username", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false)).build());

dynamoDBMapper.save(newUser, saveExpr);
```

Source: https://blog.jayway.com/2013/08/24/create-entity-if-not-exists-in-dynamodb-from-java/

EDIT: Here's my implementation of it in practice. Extremely easy to implement:

```
public Statement saveIfNotExist(Statement statement) throws ConditionalCheckFailedException {
    return mapper.save(statement, new DynamoDBSaveExpression().withExpected(ImmutableMap.of("id", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false))));
}
```

with passing unit test:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = ConditionalCheckFailedException.class)
public void shouldNotProcessIdenticalStatementUpdateInstances() {
    Statement statement1 = StatementTestBuilder.valid().build();
    Statement statement2 = StatementTestBuilder.valid().withId(statement1.getId()).build();

    statementRepository.saveIfNotExist(statement1);
    statementRepository.saveIfNotExist(statement2);
}
```