# How to use DynamoDB conditional putItem on a non primary key attribute to guarantee uniqueness?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am implementing a feature called default naming for one of our product and I would like to see how conditional putItem can help me achieve our business logic need.

Here is the problem:

We have a legacy dynamoDB table which stores some entity information. The schema is: entityId, name, manufacturer

entityId is primary key and it is actually an UUID, name and manufacturer are just attributes.

Now our feature needs to generate a default name when we insert a new entry to the table. The default name needs to be unique per manufacturer, and we would like to use sequential number to represent it.

E.g. In the table we have 2 existing items

```
123,  lucy, apple
3672, tom, apple
```

now if I want to insert another entry of manufacturer apple to the table, I need to generate “third” as the name attribute

```
5678, third, apple
```

It seems easy, I can just do a read on all the entities of apple and get a count, then use count+1 as the default value for the name attribute.

However, our system is distributed, multiple request may come in, and race condition may happen. If I don’t do any prevention. Two requests may insert two entries into the table

```
5678, third, apple
9374, third, apple
```

instead we actual wants them to be

```
5678, third, apple
9374, forth, apple
```

or

```
5678, forth, apple
9374, third, apple
```

To solve the problem what I am thinking is using putItem with ConditionalExpression. For the above example, first do a read, got the count 2, then if two concurrent requests try to insert

"5678, third, apple"  and "9374, third, apple" into the table, then one of them should got an exception, and we can increment the count again and retry.

The code of would be

```
try {
    Expected expect = new Expected("name").notExist();
    PutItemSpec putItemSpec = new PutItemSpec().withItem(item).withExpected(expected);
   entityTable.putItem(putItemSpec);
} catch (ConditionalExpression ex) {
   .. increment count and do retry
}
```

However I found that doesn’t work, there is no exception thrown. Am I misunderstanding the conditional put? How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: Using ConditionalExpression this way can't help you to ensure uniqueness of a non-key field. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823543/dynamodbmapper-save-item-only-if-unique/42973565#42973565). It seems to fit exactly to your situation.

Comment: @xtx ok thanks. Your post can solve my problem. But I do have a question on the conditional put, does conditional put only works on attribute that is hash key?

Answer (score 3):

**ConditionExpression cannot be used for this purpose**. ConditionExpression can be a bit misleading in DynamoDB for those coming from the RDBMS world. It is not to be thought of as an RDBMS table constraint check.

**Explanation**

ConditionExpression is specified on **PutItem**, **UpdateItem**, and **DeleteItem** operations. These operations operate on a **unique key** as defined for the table, which could be either just a hash key or a hash + sort key.

So, when these operations are run, the unique key identifies a unique item in the table. The cases could be as follows

- PutItem - another item with the same unique key already exists
- UpdateItem - the item to be updated is found
- DeleteItem - the item to be deleted is found

The ConditionExpression just **operates on this selected item** to perform the condition check. So it cannot be used to check conditions on other items in the same table, to potentially check for uniqueness among other non key attributes.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

**Recommendation**

To handle this case appropriately, the key design for the table should be reviewed. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html

**Update Dec-21**

Some time later I had come across this approach for additional constraint checking suggested in aws blogs, and had found it very useful. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/